# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setDelegate_' how can I fix this?

Tags: python, macos, notifications, kivy, kivymd

Basically I'm pretty new to python and kivy, and was trying to create a timer app which gives out a notification after 20 minutes to rest your eyes. I used plyer to set out the notification, and I am on mac. Usually the notification does not work because of a pyobjus error but I worked around that. But now I'm left with this new error.

> runfile('/Users/oats/Downloads/LEAF 1.0/Source Code/LEAF 0.6 .py',
> wdir='/Users/oats/Downloads/LEAF 1.0/Source Code') Traceback (most
> recent call last):
>
> File "/Users/oats/Downloads/LEAF 1.0/Source Code/LEAF 0.6 .py", line
> 218, in 
> class LeafApp(MDApp):
>
> File "/Users/oats/Downloads/LEAF 1.0/Source Code/LEAF 0.6 .py", line
> 240, in LeafApp
> notifyMe("Hey You! take a break now !!", "You should follow the 20-20-20 rule to keep your eyes healthy")
>
> File "/Users/oats/Downloads/LEAF 1.0/Source Code/LEAF 0.6 .py", line
> 231, in notifyMe
> notification.notify(
>
> File
> "/Users/oats/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plyer/facades/notification.py",
> line 79, in notify
> self._notify(
>
> File
> "/Users/oats/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plyer/platforms/macosx/notification.py",
> line 38, in *notify
> usrnotifctr.setDelegate*(self)
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setDelegate_'

is the full error message. My code is below.

'''

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDDatePicker
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.theming import ThemableBehavior
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import MDNavigationDrawer
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ListProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from plyer import notification
import time
import plyer


Config.set('graphics', 'width', '1600')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '1200')


KV = '''
<Box@BoxLayout>:
    bg: .65, .48, .35, 1 
       
             

BoxLayout:
    Rectangle:    
        size: 1600, 1200

    Box:
        bg: app.theme_cls.bg_light
    Box:
        bg: app.theme_cls.bg_normal
    Box:
        bg: app.theme_cls.bg_dark
    Box:
        bg: app.theme_cls.bg_darkest
            
'''
            
screen_helper = """
ScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
    HomeScreen:
    BreakScreen:
    SettingsScreen
        
<MenuScreen>:
    name: 'menu'
    
  
        
    MDLabel:
        rectangle:
        background_color: .65, .48, .35, 1           
        size: 300, 700
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1, 'center_y':0.0}
        
                
    MDLabel:
        text: "Welcome to"
        font_style: 'H2'
        size:500, 500
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.95,'center_y':0.84}
        
    MDLabel:
        text: "LEAF"
        font_style: 'H3'
        size:500, 500
        pos_hint: {'center_x':1.045,'center_y':0.7}
        
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Calendar'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.091,'center_y':0.65}
        on_release: app.show_date_picker()
            
            
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Home'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.076,'center_y':0.57}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Settings'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.09,'center_y':0.49}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        
            
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Continue'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.61,'center_y':0.345}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'home'
   


    
<HomeScreen>:
    name: 'home'    
                
        
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        title: "Home
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 5
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
        
    Widget:

        MDNavigationDrawer:
            id: nav_drawer
    
            ContentNavigationDrawer:
                orientation: 'vertical'
                padding: "8dp"
                spacing: "8dp"
                

                MDFlatButton:
                    text: 'Return to menu'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    on_release: root.manager.current = 'menu'

                MDFlatButton:
                    text: 'Open Calendar'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    on_release: app.show_date_picker()
                    
                MDFlatButton:
                    text: 'Open Settings'
                    font_style: 'Subtitle1'
                    on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'



    
                    
                    
                            
                
                
            
    
<BreakScreen>:
    name: 'break'
    
<SettingsScreen>:
    name: 'settings'
    
    
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Return to menu'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.1,'center_y':0.05}
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'menu'
        
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Change Theme'
        font_style: 'H6'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.85,'center_y':0.95}
        on_release: app.show_theme_picker() 
        
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: 'moon-waning-crescent'
        theme_text_color: "Custom"
        md_bg_color: 0, 0.039, 0.867, 0.557
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.3}
        on_press: self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"  # "Light"
        
    MDFloatingActionButton:
        icon: 'MDFloatingActionButton'
        icon: 'lightbulb'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.9,'center_y':0.1}
        on_press: self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Light"  # "Dark"
        
        
"""  

class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):
    pass


class BreakScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SettingsScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ContentNavigationDrawer(BoxLayout):
    pass

class DrawerList(ThemableBehavior, MDList):
    pass


    
sm = ScreenManager()
sm.add_widget(MenuScreen(name='menu'))
sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='profile'))
sm.add_widget(BreakScreen(name='upload'))
sm.add_widget(SettingsScreen(name='settings'))



class LeafApp(MDApp):
    
    def show_date_picker(self):
        date_dialog = MDDatePicker()
        date_dialog.open()

    def show_theme_picker(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()



    def notifyMe(ttle, msg):
        notification.notify(
            title = ttle,
            message = msg,
            timeout = 10,
    )


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        while True:
            notifyMe("Hey You! take a break now !!", "You should follow the 20-20-20 rule to keep your eyes healthy")
            time.sleep(1200)
            



    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
    
LeafApp().run()
'''
```

Thanks again to anybody reaching out. I'm completely confused and need help!

Comment: Not sure why you are getting that error, but your `LeafApp` will never run because your code goes into a an infinite loop (`while True`) before the app can even be started.

Comment: See man thats what I thought but for some reason idk why if I take out the timer thing it works perfectly. I-I don't even know

Answer (score 0):

Try a slight refactoring of your code, like this:

```
def notifyMe(self, ttle, msg):  # added "self" arg
    notification.notify(
        title=ttle,
        message=msg,
        timeout=10,
    )

def timer_loop(self):
    while True:
        self.notifyMe("Hey You! take a break now !!", "You should follow the 20-20-20 rule to keep your eyes healthy")
        time.sleep(1200)

def build(self):
    # run timer as a separate thread
    threading.Thread(target=self.timer_loop, daemon=True).start()

    screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
    return screen
```

Comment: New error! Code runs now though because of your refactoring (tsym). So code works but notification doesn't? Pretty stuck on this..
     notification.notify(
   File "/Users/oats/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plyer/facades/notification.py", line 79, in notify
     self._notify(
   File "/Users/oats/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/plyer/platforms/macosx/notification.py", line 38, in _notify
     usrnotifctr.setDelegate_(self)
 AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'setDelegate_'
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop

Comment: Hey man I basically completely changed the code and it works. Now I just need to make some sort of timer where the notification plays after twnety minutes but the twnenty minute timer starts when a button is pressed. Hopefully I'll figure it out. Thx again man!

Comment: class LeafApp(MDApp):

    def show_theme_picker(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()
            

    def notify(title, text):
        os.system("""
              osascript -e 'display notification "{}" with title "{}"'
              """.format(text, title))

    notify("LEAF", "Hey, its been twenty minutes, take a break?")
    
    
    
    def build(self):
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen

LeafApp().run()